# Is "the team HAD not won any match last year" correct? Shouldn't it be "the team DID not win..."?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The West Indies team had not won any match last year.

This question came in my exam , I corrected 'did not win'

But they are saying no error ....

Is there any possibility to use HAD like this?

Comment: There is _every_ possibility. Have you learnt to conjugate the English verb _win_? This is a perfectly grammatical use of the _past perfect_ of the verb _win_, however clumsy and unidiomatic it may be. (The plural _matches_ would be more idiomatic, but this is to be expected, because the exam was probably written by someone who doesn't speak English!)

Answer (score 2):

> The West Indies team had not won any match last year.

makes no sense to me (as a native British English speaker).

Firstly it needs to either be **a match** or **any matches**. Secondly "had won" only works if "until / up to a certain point" is used.

Some grammatical options are:

> - The West Indies team **did** not **win** any matches last year.
> - The West Indies team **have** not won any matches **this** year.
> - The West Indies team had not won any matches **by August** last year.
> - The West Indies team had not won any matches **until** last year..

In any of my above options **a match** could be used instead of **any matches**.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that it should be "matches".

"Not any" always takes a plural or non-counted noun. When used with a singular noun it has the meaning of "Not just any [thing] but a particular, special [thing]".